# Can I develop games with Unity on cloud without installation?

Tags: unity

I want to start game development, ideally I would only code with C# on Visual Studio with some Visual Studio extensions, without installing other extra software on my laptop.

As Unity seems to be the best choice for Game Dev, is there any chance to use it completely on the cloud without install any software (like a "SaaS – Software as a Service")?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can by using virtual desktop cloud or cloud pc, but you need to install Unity and everything else needed on the cloud computer, and also install the software that is required to access the cloud computer on your laptop. **Disclaimer: I never tried it myself**. You also need to look at the latency, latency above 100ms might be frustrating to use, and it might also takes a lot of internet data, so be careful with it.

You may also need to install operating system on the cloud computer before you can use it (windows, linux, etc), which is difficult if you don't know how. But it is quite likely that this is going to change in the future where os installation will be easy, i don't see the reason why it won't.

Example of cloud pc : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-365

Answer (score 0):

Unity development typically requires local installation due to resource-intensive tasks. However, cloud-based solutions like Unity Cloud Build allow collaboration and continuous integration without requiring the full Unity editor installation on each developer's machine.

Comment: This answer would be more directly useful if it described *how* to use Cloud Build to collaborate on a Unity project without a full editor installation. What would the steps be to set this up, and what are the limitations (e.g. submitting only code, no access to the editor interface for arranging scene content)?